# Counting vertex covers of size ((r+1)/2) +1 for an odd hole of size r

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

We know that for an odd hole of size r, its minimum vertex cover size = OPT = (r+1)/2. Furthermore, there are r such minimum vertex covers.

Was curious to know how many vertex covers exist of size OPT + 1.

Comment: We know a priori that the answer can't be $\Omega(r^r)$, since there are only $2^r$ possible vertex sets, not all of which are vertex covers and not all of which have the right size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, let $r = 2k+1$. Then we are looking for a vertex cover of $C_{2k+1}$ of size $k+2$.

Let the "structure" of a vertex cover with a specified starting vertex denote the sequence of distances between adjacent vertices. These distances must be either $1$ or $2$ because we have a vertex cover; there are $k+2$ distances, and they add up to $2k+1$. If all $k+2$ distances were $2$, we'd get $2k+4$; so exactly $3$ distances must be $1$, instead. The number of ways to choose which distances are $1$ is $\binom{k+2}{3}$.

Given the structure of a vertex cover, there are $2k+1$ ways to choose which vertex is the starting vertex, but there are also $k+2$ ways to mark a starting vertex on any given vertex cover. So the number of vertex covers is $\frac{2k+1}{k+2}\binom{k+2}{3}$, or $\frac{r^3-r}{12}$.

The answer is polynomial, not exponential, so there is no deep insight to find.

Comment: To conclude, is there any value of m such that counting covers of size OPT + m (where m <= (r-1)/2 since the maximum cover size = r) is exponential?

Comment: Well, it will always be polynomial in $m$ by pretty much the same argument, and from the other end if we are counting covers of size $r - k$ it will be polynomial in $k$ (because as an upper bound there are $\binom rk$ ways to remove $k$ vertices). But this allows for exponential counts in the middle: e.g., there are exponentially many covers of size about $\frac34r$.

Comment: Agreed. Would you say there are exponentially many covers in the range m <= (r-1)/4 ?

Comment: For any $m = \alpha r$, it is probably exponential.